# Why does my simple script tag break the following script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am tearing my hair out over this. Why is foo() undefined when I click the button in this script?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./app2.js"/>
        <script">
            function foo() {
                console.log('foo...');
            }
        </script>
        <button type="button" onClick="foo()" id="testbutton">Click!</button>
        <button type="button" onClick="hello()">Click hello!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

but not if I remove the first script tag?

```
<html>
    <body>
<!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="./app2.js"/>-->
        <script>
            function foo() {
                console.log('foo...');
            }
        </script>
        <button type="button" onClick="foo()" id="testbutton">Click!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

My app2.js is just

```
function hello() {
    console.log('hello');
}
```

I have tested in Chrome and Safari on macOS. The hello function works as expected.

Comment: You have an extra double quote `<script">` that should be removed. Not sure if that's just a typo in the question though

Comment: I get `hello is not defined`, is this what you mean?

Comment: You can't self close a script tag - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-elements-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto closing tags are used in React JSX and not in vanilla HTML
Replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app2.js"/>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app2.js" ></script>
```